# Vue js applications code throws error (Js Expected)

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js

I am trying to build vue js applications but I am  getting following errors .

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning TS1005  (JS) ':' expected.  VuejsApp JavaScript Content Files   C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\VuejsApp\VuejsApp\src\App.vue   19  Active**

This is Home.vue code

```
<template>
    <div id="databinding">
        <div id="counter-event-example">
            <p style="font-size:25px;">Language displayed : <b>{{ languageclicked }}</b></p>
            <button-counter v-for="(item, index) in languages"
                            v-bind:item="item"
                            v-bind:index="index"
                            v-on:showlanguage="languagedisp"></button-counter>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
   // import Home from './components/Home.vue';
  //  import component1 from './components/component1.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        Vue.components('button-counter', {
            template: '<button v-on:click = "displayLanguage(item)"><span style = "font-size:25px;">{{ item }}</span></button>',
            data: function () {
                return {
                    counter: 0
                }
            },
            props: ['item'],
            methods: {
                displayLanguage: function (lng) {
                    console.log(lng);
                    this.$emit('showlanguage', lng);
                }
            },
        });
         new Vue({
            el: '#databinding',
            data: {
                languageclicked: "",
                languages: ["Java", "PHP", "C++", "C", "Javascript", "C#", "Python", "HTML"]
            },
            methods: {
                languagedisp: function (a) {
                    this.languageclicked = a;
                }
            }
        })
    };


</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I want to display list of buttons and when i clicked the any of them button , I want to display the message that button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error is related to the component. First, the function name is wrong. The correct name is `Vue.component` and it is `Vue.components`. Second, your component declaration is not correct.

I created [this codepen](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/qzgGyG) where you can see how to declare the component globally and locally.

```js
const buttonCounter = {
 template:
  `<button @click="displayLanguage(item)">
   <span style="font-size:25px;">{{ item }}</span>
  </button>`,
 props: ["item"],
 methods: {
  displayLanguage: function(lng) {
   this.$emit("show-language", lng);
  }
 }
}


// Declare your component globally, will be able to access it in any another component in the application
Vue.component("button-counter", buttonCounter );

new Vue({
 el: "#databinding",
  // declarete your component locally, it only will be available inside this context
 components:{
  'button-counter-2' : buttonCounter
 },
 data: function() {
  return {
   languageclicked: "",
   languages: ["Java", "PHP", "C++", "C", "Javascript", "C#", "Python", "HTML"]
  };
 },
 methods: {
  languageDisp: function(a) {
   this.languageclicked = a;
  }
 }
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 20px;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="databinding">
 <div id="counter-event-example">
  <p style="font-size:25px;">Language displayed : <b>{{ languageclicked }}</b></p>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
   <button-counter v-for="(item, index) in languages" :item="item"  :key="item" @show-language="languageDisp"/>
  </div>
  <button-counter-2 v-for="(item, index) in languages" :item="item" :key="item"  @show-language="languageDisp"/>
 </div>
</div>
```